# Choosing a chained select option with jquery using Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm not much good at jquery and ajax, and I'm now having difficulties on a select box. I use CI and My code is below.

Another select box "category" data will be show according to the "brand". How can I carry data from "brand" and show data in "category" with jquery?

View

```
<select name="brand" class="form-control" id="brand" required>
    <?php
        if($items) {
            foreach($items as $key) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key->brand_id ?>">
        <?php echo $key->brand_name ?>
    </option>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>

<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" required>

</select>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#brand").on('change', function() {
            var brand = $(this).val();
            $.ajax ({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>receiving/showCategory",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'brand='+brand,

                success: function(msg) {
                    var options;
                    for(var i = 0; i<msg.length; i++) {
                        options = '<option>'+msg.category[i].category_name+'</option'>;
                    }
                    $('#category').html(options);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
function showCategory() {
    $brand_id = $this->input->post('brand');
    $data['category'] = $this->item_model->category($brand_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

My category table contains: category_id, category_name, brand_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use ajax onchange. .in your view file.. 

<select name="brand" class="form-control" id="brand" required onchange="brand(this.value,'divid')">
    <?php
        if($items) {
            foreach($items as $key) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key->brand_id ?>">
        <?php echo $key->brand_name ?>
    </option>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
<div id="divid">
<select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" required>
<option>Select Category</option>
</select>
</div>



<script>
    function brand(id,divid)
    {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "pid="+id,
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>receiving/showCategory ?>',
            success: function(html){
                $('#'+divid).html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

in your function showCategory()  :

```
<div id="divid">
    <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" required>
$brandid = $this->input->post('pid');
//you can pass this brand id to your query and echo the category in option value//   

<option>//your result //</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like your code is correct, but need to change a little bit in ajax request. 
You need to parse the data return into `parseJson` first. The `options` variable in for loop should concatenate with `+=` code. See example below:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#brand").on('change', function() {
        var brand = $(this).val();
        $.ajax ({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>receiving/showCategory",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'brand='+brand,

            success: function(msg) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(msg),options;
                for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option>'+data.category[i].category_name+'</option'>;
                }
                $('#category').html(options);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In case you have a problem with this code, you should change variable in codeigniter part for the variable that hold the results. You can see my working code below as an example :

**Js Code**

```
       $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          url  : '<?php echo base_url();?>controller/function_name',
          dateType : 'json',
          data : {depart_id : _depart_id.val()},
          success : function(data){
            var json_data = $.parseJSON(data),
                options;
            for(var i = 0; i<json_data.length; i++){
              options += '<option value="'+json_data[i].destination_id+'">'+json_data[i].location+'</option>';
            }
            _destination_id.html(options);
          }
        });
```

**Here is codeigniter code(php)**

```
$destination  = $this->custom_model->get_destination_distinct($table,$where);
echo json_encode($destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat the all values in success function like

```
  options += '<option>'+msg.category[i].category_name+'</option'>;

  $('#category').html(options);
```